# Terraform use case to create multiple almost identical copies of infrastructure

Tags: terraform

I have TF templates whose purpose is to create multiple copies of the same cloud infrastructure. For example you have multiple business units inside a big organization, and you want to build out the same basic networks. Or you want an easy way for a developer to spin up the stack that he's working on. The only difference between "tf apply" invokations is the variable BUSINESS_UNIT, for example, which is passed in as an environment variable.

Is anyone else using a system like this, and if so, how do you manage the state files ?

Comment: Why do you think the state file management for this use case is any different to any other case?

Comment: No fundamental difference, but TF still could have a mode of operation that makes my scenario more seamless. I'll just have a simple shell wrapper to achieve this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should use a [Terraform Module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html). Creating a module is nothing special: just put any Terraform templates in a folder. What makes a module special is how you use it.

Let's say you put the Terraform code for your infrastructure in the folder `/terraform/modules/common-infra`. Then, in the templates that actually define your live infrastructure (e.g. `/terraform/live/business-units/main.tf`), you could use the module as follows:

```
module "business-unit-a" {
  source = "/terraform/modules/common-infra"
}
```

To create the infrastructure for multiple business units, you could use the same module multiple times:

```
module "business-unit-a" {
  source = "/terraform/modules/common-infra"
}

module "business-unit-b" {
  source = "/terraform/modules/common-infra"
}

module "business-unit-c" {
  source = "/terraform/modules/common-infra"
}
```

If each business unit needs to customize some parameters, then all you need to do is define an [input variable](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/variables.html) in the module (e.g. under `/terraform/modules/common-infra/vars.tf`):

```
variable "business_unit_name" {
  description = "The name of the business unit"
}
```

Now you can set this variable to a different value each time you use the module:

```
module "business-unit-a" {
  source = "/terraform/modules/common-infra"
  business_unit_name = "a"
}

module "business-unit-b" {
  source = "/terraform/modules/common-infra"
  business_unit_name = "b"
}

module "business-unit-c" {
  source = "/terraform/modules/common-infra"
  business_unit_name = "c"
}
```

For more information, see [How to create reusable infrastructure with Terraform modules](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d) and *[Terraform: Up & Running](http://www.terraformupandrunning.com/)*.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways of doing this that jump to mind.

Firstly, you could go down the route of using the same Terraform configuration folder that you apply and simply pass in a variable when running Terraform (either via the command line or through environment variables). You'd also want to have the same wrapper script that calls Terraform to configure your state settings to make them differ.

This might end up with something like this:

```
variable "BUSINESS_UNIT" {}
variable "ami" { default = "ami-123456" }

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami = "${var.ami}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags {
        Name = "web"
        Business_Unit = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
    }
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.6.17"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "db_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.6"
}
```

Which creates an EC2 instance and an RDS instance. You would then call that with something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters - specify business unit as positional parameter"
fi

business_unit=$1

terraform remote config -backend="s3" \
                        -backend-config="bucket=${business_unit}" \
                        -backend-config="key=state"

terraform remote pull

terraform apply -var 'BUSINESS_UNIT=${business_unit}'

terraform remote push
```

As an alternative route you might want to consider using modules to wrap your Terraform configuration.

So instead you might have something that now looks like:

### web-instance/main.tf

```
variable "BUSINESS_UNIT" {}
variable "ami" { default = "ami-123456" }

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami = "${var.ami}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags {
        Name = "web"
        Business_Unit = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
    }
}
```

### db-instance/main.tf

```
variable "BUSINESS_UNIT" {}

resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 10
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.6.17"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
  username             = "foo"
  password             = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name = "db_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.6"
}
```

And then you might have different folders that call these modules per business unit:

### business-unit-1/main.tf

```
variable "BUSINESS_UNIT" { default = "business-unit-1" }

module "web_instance" {
  source = "../web-instance"
  BUSINESS_UNIT = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
}

module "db_instance" {
  source = "../db-instance"
  BUSINESS_UNIT = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
}
```

and

### business-unit-2/main.tf

```
variable "BUSINESS_UNIT" { default = "business-unit-2" }

module "web_instance" {
  source = "../web-instance"
  BUSINESS_UNIT = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
}

module "db_instance" {
  source = "../db-instance"
  BUSINESS_UNIT = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
}
```

You still need a wrapper script to manage state configuration as before but going this route enables you to provide a rough template in your modules and then hard code certain extra configuration by business unit such as the instance size or the number of instances that are built for them.

Comment: Good point @Pandem1c, I've edited to remove that unnecessary usage.

Comment: Good on ya, mate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather popular use case. To archive this you can let developers to pass variable from command-line or from tfvars file into resource to make different resources unique:

main.tf:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
  identifier = "${var.BUSINESS_UNIT}"
  # ... read more in docs
}
```

---

```
$ terraform apply -var 'BUSINESS_UNIT=unit_name'
```

PS: We do this often to provision infrastructure for specific git branch name, and since all resources are identifiable and are located in separate tfstate files, we can safely destroy them when we don't need them.

Comment: This approach has a problem: Terraform stores state every time you run it. Therefore, each time you ran `terraform apply` for a new business unit, you'd be overwriting the previous business unit. You can force Terraform to store the state separately each time, but that's very messy compared to using modules. See [How to manage Terraform state](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa) and [How to create reusable infrastructure with Terraform modules](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d) for more info.

Comment: Hi Jim. I organise infrastructure into layers, which consists of modules. Each layer has its own state file stored on S3 and available as remote state for other layers. There is simple shell script which manages state files (together with Terragrunt). Not so messy, as it may sound. See [How I structure Terraform configurations](http://www.antonbabenko.com/2016/09/21/how-i-structure-terraform-configurations.html). Have a great day :)